# Fae book about an orphaned girl who discovers her father was fae and she inherited powers

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read this book around 2010–2013.

The book started with a girl who was orphaned. She was getting picked up by her social worker and was wearing a green sweatshirt. (I only remember this fact because I then tried to find a sweater to match).

She ends up at this town and meets a guy who helps her discover her heritage. It turns out her father is a faery and she has some powers that she needs to learn about. I think the guy was fae too? I am not too sure, but I remember something about how she is special to the survival and they escape some kind of battle at the end. (Of course the guy and girl fall in love.)

I can't remember any character names or locations.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember the cover art?  What were her powers?

Comment: Something about being able to break through glass and maybe go between the worlds? I thought it might be Glimmerglass or Switched because the descriptions looked familiar but I don't think it's those.

Comment: It's great that you've found the answer!  Please post it below so that everyone else can know too.